# Observable pattern redundancy in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

The [Observable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) module uses `change` method as a way of toggling when the observers should get updates of any change in state in the Subject. However, it seems redundant to me, as notify_observers(self) it is going to be called intentionally. Is there a situation where having `change` makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows for a split in timing, and for multiple changes without side effects.

- The state of an object may or may not change during a sub-process of an application. If it changes, then `.change` can be invoked without any side effects. It is also possible to call it multiple times.
- Later, notifications can be sent. As long as they are sent before any dependent actions are taken, then anything that depends on updates due to the original change should be able to make its update correctly

You might do this for example if processing following a change had a high cost (I/O, CPU time, network bandwidth), but only needed to be done *before* a second section of code, not simply every time a change occurred.

You might also do this if updates are not strictly necessary in all code paths. I.e. sometimes you care about updating due to a change, but other times it is not necessary, and any change can be ignored.

An example might be if you need to re-generate an XML document every time a content object used by the XML creation code has a property change. You would place calls to `.change` in the important property setters of the content object, hiding them from the external caller. You don't want to generate a new XML document each time you call `content.property=` (it could be very slow), instead you wait until you are finished making updates and place a single call to `content.notify_observers` after all possible changes.